# Assigning percentile values to long list of stocks in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 700+ stocks:

```
excesslist.nlargest(5)
OLED    4.551521
NBIX    4.538618
ALNY    4.526540
AMD     4.502308
IONS    4.484968
...
```

I want to give each stock to a value (of 1/100th percentile).  For example, the top 1% get a score of .99 , the top 2% get a score of .98 ... the bottom 1% would get .01 .

Haven't able to use np.percentile to increment ea value and just stuck with having to do it manually, and unsure how to assign values:

```
In: np.percentile(excesslist,[0,1,2,3])

Out: array([ 0.72803527,  0.78873332,  0.83364907,  0.85492285])
```

Expected output is to have ea 1/100th percentile of the list to be assigned a common value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise a dataframe, and then use [`df.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stocks' : excesslist})
df['Percentile'] = pd.qcut(df.Stocks, 100, labels=False) / 100
```

Comment: ok that worked - but how do I assign values to the percentiles?

Comment: @thomas.mac Try `df['Percentile'] /= 100`?

Comment: Thats a great answer +1

Comment: Thanks  a lot that was easy to understand , I was using qcut w/o creating a df and getting a weird series in return

Comment: @thomas.mac Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `pct=True` parameter in the `pd.Series.rank` or `pd.DataFrame.rank` methods.

```
excesslist.rank(pct=True)
```

Comment: Assuming it is a Series... but +1

Comment: both Series and DataFrame's have the method.  And I'm assuming `excesslist` has to be a `pd.Series` considering OP use `nlargest` without a `col` parameter.

Comment: `excesslist.rank(pct=True).round(2)`